# Rotate an ellipse with vertical drag using gesture

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, silverlight-toolkit

I have downloaded the windows phone toolkit from codeplex that enables the phone to receive gesture support. In my application, I have an ellipse. I want to create a method that will rotate the ellipse Counter clockwise when the screen receives upward vertical gesture & clockwise when it receives downward vertical gesture. I've spent a lot of time on google but with poor results, how can I achieve this operation?

Comment: Apply a RotateTransform to the Ellipse, detect the vertical gesture by using the ManipulationDelta event of the page, and change the angle of the RotateTransform accordingly

Comment: I can write the RotateTransform to Ellipse but I am unable to come up with the logic to detect vertical gesture, can you give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, assign a RotateTransform to the control you want to rotate. Here I'm using a rectangle because it's easier to see it rotate, but it works just as well with an ellipse:

```
<Rectangle Fill="Blue" Height="50" Width="50">
    <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform x:Name="RotateTransform" />
    </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
</Rectangle>
```

Then, subscribe to the `ManipulationDelta` event of your page:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
    x:Class="..."
    various stuff
    ManipulationDelta="PhoneApplicationPage_ManipulationDelta">
```

In the event handler, use `e.DeltaManipulation.Translation` to know how much the finger has moved, on the X and Y axis. Then, rotate your shape accordingly:

```
private void PhoneApplicationPage_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
{
    this.RotateTransform.Angle += e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.Y;
}
```

If you want your shape to rotate at a different speed, then multiply `e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.Y` by a constant (> 1 to accelerate the rotation, < 1 to slow it down). Also, if you don't want the shape to rotate when the finger is moving diagonally, check the value of `e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.X` and apply the rotation only if it's way smaller than `e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.Y` (you can't just check if it's equal to 0, since the finger will always move slightly to the left or to the right when doing a vertical gesture).

Comment: The code works fine when I rotate my finger in either direction, but when I make a vertical gesture in up/down direction starting from the ellipse, the ellipse rotates up to 90 degrees and then stops, why is it happening?

Comment: @Sidsec9 Indeed. To be honest, I don't know how to explain this behavior. You can prevent it by setting `IsHitTestVisible="False"` on the ellipse, but that's a dirty fix.

Comment: I came up with a new solution. I copied the ellipse & pasted it over the old ellipse. The new ellipse has Opacity = 0 and your code is applied to the new ellipse to rotate the old ellipse. This works fine!